# Current stable release for EF

Tags: entity-framework

As of 6/25/2014 which is the current stable release of EF (that is not in beta). On [Codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) it says 6.1.0 and on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/),  which is official release channel for EF its says 6.1.1

Comment: Wouldn't the version in the official release channel be the current stable release? Also, the previous version listed in the NuGet gallery has "beta" in the version string ("6.1.1-beta1"), and 6.1.1 does not. 6.1.1 appears to have been released 5 days ago.

Comment: ErikEJ's answer is correct (you can mark his question as accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Version 6.1.1 is the current stable release, with 6.1.2 in the works

Comment: Thanks i wasn't sure, because codeplex shows 6.1.0 as current version. and it host official EntityFramework

Comment: Raise a Codeplex issue to get that fixed!